# What is the role of clock for a UART

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, uart

I'm busy writing a driver for a UART.  The, `struct uart_port` has a field `uartclk` [see this link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/serial_core.h?v=3.10#L125).  According to a slide set I found from free-electrons, this is among the most important fields to initialize.  Yet, the Xilinx AXI UART Lite, which I'm writing a driver for, doesn't initialize this member [see this link to see](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/uartlite.c).

I'm wondering about the importance of this field.  What is this in relation to a UART?  Why is it important?  What role does it play in the serial core?

Thanks

P.S.  I know there's a driver existing.  However, this driver assumes the UART Lite is to be used in an embedded environment.  In the application I'm writing to, this is not the case.

Comment: Pretty much all modern logic operates synchronous to a clock.  In the case of a UART, it is customary to use a clock that is 8x or 16x the baud rate.  The transmitter uses counters based on this to advance state and generate output, while the receiver samples the input at this rate looking for the start bit and then samples a suitable number of clock periods thereafter to measure the data at the most reliable point in the waveform of each bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UART like any other IP in the system has to have functional and interface clocks. In some IPs it might be same clock, in some it might be more interface or functional clocks. The `uartclk` field reflects the actual frequency on the input to baudrate generator (don't be confused by the frequency of functional clock which most of the time is constant). When user calls termios to set a desired baudrate the UART driver for actual hardware recalculates `uartclk`, if needed, and bottom layer, if used, configures the registers. That's how 8250 works. In other cases it might be left unused, if, for example, serial hw driver does everything on its own.

Comment: Thank you.  This does help to clarify.  For this particular part, or IP, I believe the clock rate is fixed.  At least, the hardware engineer  has told me that the settings are configured by him and not alterable at runtime by software.

Comment: Under linux, is there a way to query the `uartclk` (as well as divisor) of a serial port? If yes, how such information is obtained by kernel (or kernel modules) in the scenario of dynamically plugging in an USB2Uart dongle? Thanks!

Comment: @bruin I am not sure I understood the second part of the question, but for the first I don’t think this information is available to the user space. Or are you asking how kernel gets it? It completely depends on the hardware and platform in question.

Comment: @0andriy I also digged a bit more. it seems that for some drivers (at least the two I checked, ftdi 232h and pl2303, both USB2Uart), the uart clock is just hard coded in the source file, be it 12MHz or 48Mhz, probably according to their datasheet... For the 2nd part, I was assuming that kernel should know the uart clock value, but it seems that kernel may not need to know that, kernel passes baudrate to the driver, and driver tells back to the kernel if the baudrate is doable or not.

Comment: @bruin, in case of USB dongles the clock usually fixed, when it's not true the additional property should come from somewhere to express the clock rate. Otherwise the baud rate can't be properly calculated. See. for example, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/tty.git/commit/?id=24bc6e68efa00f95034dbef0ba91661dd80bd37d or https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/tty.git/commit/?id=d4d6f03c4fb3a91dadfe147b47edd40e4d7e4d36.